# pycurl, how to send POST data for Multiple Select Form?

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, libcurl, pycurl

I'm trying to do some webscraping, and it involves sending a form with a Multiple Select Box List that looks similar to this:

```
<select name="multipleSelectForm" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

Now, I want to send both value1 and value2 using pycurl, for example:

```
import urllib
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()

data = {'multipleSelectForm':'value1',
        'multipleSelectForm':'value2'}

c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.example.com')

c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
post = urllib.urlencode(data)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, post)

c.perform()
```

now the obvious problem with this is that it's sending multipleSelectForm multiple times. I'm quite sure that the requested page is probably looking for a multipleSelectForm array, and not just individual variables (this is just a guess, I'm not actually sure) and hence that POST data it receives isn't correct.

I tried using Google Chrome's dev tools to see the traffic of what it's doing and when I looked at the Form Data, it looked like this:

```
multipleSelectForm:value1
multipleSelectForm:value2
```

I'm a bit lost on how to approach all of this, if anybody would care to help

Answer (score 1):

From that it looks like the data you're sending is going to just be

```
{ 'multipleSelectForm':'value2' }
```

Because it's a dictionary. If you set it up as tuple pairs it will do what you want.

```
data = (('multipleSelectForm', 'value1'), ('multipleSelectForm', 'value2'))
```

You can test this your self by setting up a tiny debug http server:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

class hand(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):                                          
    def __init__(self, socket, *args):                                       
        print socket.recv(10000)                                             

server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), hand)                                        
server.serve_forever()
```

and then hitting it with your script. I used this to confirm that passing the tuple list does what I expect.